# Delete 3 identical words from a text not all

Tags: c#, string

I want to delete **3** words called `"apple"` from a string of textbox.
Textbox contain *more* than 3 *apple* words. I need to select *only 3* to delete.

I used this code but it delete all apple words from the string.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Replace("apple","");
}
```

I want to delete 3 words only. Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

[image: Please see the image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far to solve it

Comment: Please be more specific. Have you made _any_ attempt whatsoever to improve on the code you already have? If you only want to replace three instances, does it matter which instances? At this point, your question is basically just asking us to write a correct implementation for you, which is not the reason for Stack Overflow's existence.

Comment: I will edit again

Comment: I try to do it from a for loop. after typing the code i realized it doesn't work... 

       String GOT = sb.ToString();

            for(int j=0;j< Convert.ToInt32(cwatchers.Max())-Convert.ToInt32(cwatchers[j]);j++) 
            {

                MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
                //GOT=GOT.Replace("URL GOTO=www.ebay.com/itm"+cwatchers[j],"");

            }

           // textBox3.Text = GOT;
        }

Comment: Please update your question with new informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to look for the word "apple" three times (or less if it doesn't appear three times) in your string and to remove it from your current string.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string stringToRemove = "apple";

    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    string textBoxString = textBox3.Text;

    while(i<3 && index >= 0)
    {
        index = textBoxString.IndexOf(stringToRemove);

        textBoxString = (index < 0)? textBoxString : textBoxString.Remove(index, stringToRemove.Length);
        i++;
    }

    textBox3.Text = textBoxString;
}
```

Comment: no. this is not working... it removes all apple words

Comment: @user3398379 Are you sure you have the `i++` at the end? It can't change it more than 3 times here.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the overload of [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) to specify the maximum number of times to replace

```
var regex = new Regex("apple");
var newText = regex.Replace(textBox3.Text, "", 3);
```

Comment: If `apple` could be a different value (e.g. `apple.`) consider calling https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx on the string.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another possibility is to `Split` (treating `"apple"` as a *separator*) and `Concat` back:

```
// 3 + 1: we want 3 separators to be eliminated, and thus 4 = 3 + 1 parts 
textBox3.Text = string.Concat(textBox3.Text
  .Split(new string[] { "apple" }, 3 + 1, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

Comment: with the help of string.Join you can also change it to a Replace method ;o)

Comment: @Sir Rufo: quite right, but `string.Concat(...)` is shorter and more readable then `string.Join("", ...)`

Comment: Of course and following KISS yours is the right solution for this. My comment is for future readers asking themself how should it be done for a Replace

Answer (score -3):

There`s multiple way to accomplish what you want. 1 of is is using regex, and 1 of is as sample below, basically loop and replace on how many time u want it to be.

```
string value = textBox3.Text;
for(int a = 0; a < 2;a++){
value = value.replace("apple","");
}

textBox3.Text=value;
```

Comment: Nope, that will even not compile